# Smash and join products of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to prove rigorously that $\mathbb S^n \wedge \mathbb S^m =\mathbb S^{n+m}$ and $\mathbb S^n \ast \mathbb S^m = \mathbb S^{n+m+1}$?
And what intuition should i have for compute $\wedge,\ast$ for difficult spaces?

Comment: What have you tried? As for intuition: spheres are one-point compactifications of vector spaces, i.e. $S^n$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A natural way to add vector spaces is to take their direct sum. Show that the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus \mathbb{R}^m$ is the smash product of one point compactifications.

Comment: As for *joins* one definition of these is as the suspension of the smash product... so there's that... Another way to think of them is as coming from a natural operation on simplices. If you have a $p$ simplex (on vertices $0, ..., p$) and a $q$-simplex (on vertices $0, ..., q$) it seems resonable to make a new guy by concatenating their ordered vertices to get a $p+q+1$-simplex $0, ..., p, 0,..., q$. Extending this operation of concatenation formally from simplices to simplicial complexes gives the join.

Comment: @DylanWilson If you write the above comments as an answer, I can award you the bounty.

Comment: An answer for smash products can be found here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/543205/149101.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will prove that $\mathbb{S}^n \wedge \mathbb{S}^m$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n+m}$

(Note that throughout this post $(\cdot)^*$ refers to the one-point compactification of a topological space)

> *Theorem:* Let $M$ be a compact manifold of positive dimension and let $p \in M$. Then $M$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $M \setminus \{p\}$.

Note that $\mathbb{S}^n$ is a compact manifold. Let $p$ be any point in $\mathbb{S}^n$, then utilizing the above theorem we get $$\mathbb{S}^n \cong \left(\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}\right)^*$$ where $\left(\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}\right)^*$ denotes the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$.  Note also that $$\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\} \cong \mathbb{R}^n.$$This then allows us to conclude that since the one-point compactification of a topological space is unique up to homeomorphism,   it follows that $$\left(\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}\right)^* \cong \left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)^*$$ and thus we can conclude that $$\mathbb{S}^n \cong \left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)^*. \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ (1)$$

But how does this help us? In order to prove the desired result, we need to make use of one further theorem.

> *Theorem:* If $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces then $$X \wedge Y \cong \left(X \setminus \{x\} \times Y \setminus \{x\}\right)^*$$ where $x$ and $y$ are chosen base points of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Since $\mathbb{S}^n$ and $\mathbb{S}^m$ are both compact Hausdorff spaces the above theorem implies that $$\mathbb{S}^n \wedge \mathbb{S}^m \cong \left(\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\} \times \mathbb{S}^m \setminus \{q\}\right)^*$$ and since $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{S}^m \setminus \{q\} \cong \mathbb{R}^m$ and the fact that for topological spaces $X, Y, A, B$ if $X \cong A$ and $Y \cong B$ then $X \times Y \cong A \times B$ it follows that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{S}^n \wedge \mathbb{S}^m &\cong \left(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m\right)^* \ \ \text{by the above} \\
&\cong \left(\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\right)^* \ \ \ \ \text{(since } \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \cong \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \text{)} \\
&\cong \  \mathbb{S}^{n+m} \ \ \ \  \ \  \text{by $(1)$ above}
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you please provide a proof of the theorem you have used?

Comment: For a proof of the second theorem, I would recommend the excellent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543205/smash-product-of-compact-spaces)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to give another proof for the smash product using the definition. By the definition of the smash product, we have $$S^n\wedge S^m\cong S^n\times S^m/(S^n\vee S^m).$$

Suppose $I^n=[0,1]^n\subset \mathbb R^n$ and consider $S^n$ as $I^n/\partial I^n\cong (I^n)^\mathrm o\cup O$, where $O$ is the origin of $\mathbb R^n$. Then
$$S^n\times S^m \cong (I^{n+m})^\mathrm o\cup(\partial I^n\times (I^m)^\mathrm o)\cup((I^n)^\mathrm o\times \partial I^m),$$
$$S^n\vee S^m\cong I^n\cup I^m.$$
Since $(I^{n+m})^\mathrm o/(I^n\cup I^m)\cong(I^{n+m})^\mathrm o$, $(\partial I^n\times (I^m)^\mathrm o)\cup((I^n)^\mathrm o\times \partial I^m)/(I^n\cup I^m)\cong O$, we have $S^n\wedge S^m\cong (I^{n+m})^\mathrm o\cup O\cong S^{n+m}$.

Answer (score 0):

For join, a definition of join is that we define $X*Y=X\times Y\times I/\sim$ where the relation is given by:

$$(x,y,0)\sim(x,y',0) \text{ and } (x,y,1)\sim(x',y,1)$$

for all $x,x'\in X,y,y'\in Y$. Note that, identifying $x$ with $[(x,y,0)]$ and $y$ with $[(x,y,1)]$, we naturally have a path from $x$ to $y$.

---

To prove $S^m*S^n=S^{m+n+1}$, it suffices to show that $S^m*S^0=S^{m+1}$ for all $m\ge 0$.

We have $S^m*S^0=S^m\times S^0\times I/\sim$. Say $S^0=\{x_0,x_1\}$. The relation $\sim$ "glues" two copies of $S^m\times I$ together by identifying $S^m\times \{x_0\}\times\{0\}$ with $S^m\times \{x_1\}\times\{0\}$, and then the relation $\sim$ "contracts" two copies of $S^m$ on the ends to two points (namely, it "contracts" $S^m\times \{x_0\}\times\{1\}$ to a point and
$S^m\times \{x_1\}\times\{1\}$ to another). Hence, put together, $S^m\times S^0\times I/\sim$ is just $S^m\times I$ with top and bottom "contracted" to two points! Thus $S^m\times S^0\times I/\sim\,\,=S^{m+1}$.

---

By the way, $X*S^0=\Sigma X$, the suspension of $X$, for any $X$.