# show that $\Sigma(S^1 \times S^1) \simeq S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^3 $

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hatcher in Chapter [4](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATpage.html) gives the example:  $\Sigma(S^m \times S^n) \simeq S^{m+1} \vee S^{n+1} \vee S^{m+n+1} $ relating the [suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)) and the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum).

- for example $S^1 \vee S^1 $ looks like a [figure eight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Gerono).
- $\Sigma(S^1 \times S^1) \simeq S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^3 $

There's a couple of questions here.  That wedge product is **associative** (in fact these two spaces are [homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)):
$$ (S^2 \vee S^2) \vee S^3 \simeq S^2 \vee (S^2 \vee S^3)  \tag{$\ast$}$$
The proof in the textbook also gives a homotopy equivalence:

- $ (S^1 \ast S^1) \cup CS^1 \cup CS^1 \simeq \Sigma(X \times Y) $ where $\ast$ means join and $C$ means "[cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology))".
    It is the quotient space, $CX = (X \times I) /X \times \{ 0\})$.
- the [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)) of two spaces is related to cone by $ X \ast Y \simeq (CX \times Y) \cup_{X \times Y} (CY \times X)$

I just wanted to picture what these shapes and maps look like.  Here I'm just dealing with $m = n = 1$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301402/suspension-of-a-product-tricky-homotopy-equivalence) with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160230/smash-and-join-products-of-spheres)