# Homeomorphism between Sphere and smash product

Tags: general-topology

Is there an explicit homeomorphism between the Sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ and the smash product $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \wedge \mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543205/smash-product-of-compact-spaces

Comment: Thanks, I did find this question before, and maybe I didn't see it, but I am looking for an explicit function as a homeomorphism...

Comment: Try using cylindrical coordinates, so $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and write $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as $S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}$.