# $S^k\mathbb{D}^n\simeq \mathbb{D}^{n+k+1}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactification

I'd like to prove that the $k$-th suspension of the $n$-disk, i.e $\mathbb{D}^n = \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| x \| \leq 1\right\rbrace$ is the $n+k$ disk, i.e

$$S^k\mathbb{D}^n\simeq \mathbb{D}^{n+k+1}$$

I'd like to use [Smash product of compact spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543205/smash-product-of-compact-spaces) that I was able to prove in order to do the base case(if this is the easier way), but this lead me to :

$$S\mathbb{D}^n \simeq \mathbb{S}^1 \wedge \mathbb{D}^n \simeq (\mathbb{S}^1\setminus \left\lbrace p\right\rbrace \times \mathbb{D}^n\setminus \left\lbrace x_0\right\rbrace)^*$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here noticing that this is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^{n+1}$.

From here the thesis quickly follows since $S^k\mathbb{D}^{n} = SS^{k-1}\mathbb{D}^n \simeq S\mathbb{D}^{k-1+n} \simeq \mathbb{D}^{k+n}$ using idnuction hypothesis and the $k=1$ case.

Any help hint or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a picture of suspension in your head?

Comment: @КряжевАрсений Yes, taking a "cone" on $X$ and collapse a segment of the form $x_0 \times I$. Actually in $CW$ complex should be homotopically equivalent to reduced suspension $\Sigma X$ so I imagine a cone like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)#/media/File:Suspension.svg

Comment: Cone is improper, I'm thinking of a two sided cone as in the picture linked.

Comment: Then you can notice that $\Sigma D^n$ slices into horisontal discs (plus two poles) just like $D^{n+1}$ does.

Comment: Smash product leaves you with a contracted segment in addition to that. Again some slicing would help, if you really want that.